# How to select the all the rows in jquery data table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, datatables

I have two buttons in my page "Select All" and "Deselect All". I need to select the all the rows when i click the select all button and save the list of id in my variable. When Click deselect ll button it should be deselect the all rows . How will we do that?

```
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Action Name(pssing value)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            // my code
                var MyModel = new List<List<string>>();

                foreach (var joblist in Jobs)
                {
                    var sublist = new List<string>();
                    sublist.Add(checked.false);
                    sublist.Add(values));
                    sublist.Add(values));
                    ....etc 

                    baseModel.Add(sublist);
                }

                return new DataTableResult(return);
            }
```

Html :

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="AssignJobsTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
            <th>ID</th>
          etc ......
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

script:

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
```

When i click the select all check box it cant bind the value form the controller.

Comment: paste your code,, that will be more helpful

Comment: I didnot do anything.

Comment: `I didnot do anything.` ........what? we can't produce it for you.

Comment: Please check my recent post

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('table#tableId> tbody > tr').addClass('highlight');

 $('table#tableId> tbody > tr').removeClass('highlight')addClass('noHeilight');
```

Comment: I know this but how to store the selected row id?

Comment: please unserstand my question

Comment: i understand.If you show code how you set that id then we can provide solution

Comment: Just i bind the table from my controller. i have column Id, test1, test2............. etc. Then i need to pass my value to my controller using id value

Comment: Please check my recent post

Answer (score 0):

> sample table

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    <th>Cell phone</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
    <td>3.5/5</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

sample script:

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Its helpful . but  ineed to pass the selected row in my controller so how to get the selected row id?

Comment: poor guy, when you select all the row, you should use jquery selector to get the element contains the Id and save it in an array.

Comment: I know . Please check my recent post

Answer (score 0):

you should set id attr for checkboxes and put row id in the id attr and use the below code for selecting and deselecting:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {

      var isSelect;
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        isSelect=true;
      }else{
        isSelect=false;   
      }

      $("table tr td input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){

          if(isSelect) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);

            SelectedItems+=$(this).val()+":";
          }else{
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            SelectedItems="";
          } 
          $("#Result").html(SelectedItems);

      });          
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach of keeping track of all the selected rows in a datatable.

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/plugin_api.html

The idea is to check the current page that the user is on and select/deselect the rows that is currently being viewed. You would loop through the page's rows and store the selected row into an array for future reference.

With this approach you would limit the time it takes to select/deselect all rows in the table.

Only show whats needed base on the view that user is seeing.

No hang up because the table is too busy checking/unchecking each row.

```
//stored checked box list
var result = [];
var selectAll = false;

var table5 = $('#example5').dataTable({
   'fnDrawCallback':function(oSettings){

     var anNodes = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes( oSettings );
 var anDisplay = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);

     //write your logic for pagination 
     //example 
     /*
     $('tbody tr td:first-child input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
         if($.inArray(....) != -1){push result}
       }else{
         if($.inArray(....) != -1){splice result}
       }
     }
     if(selectAll){
        for(var i = 0; i < anDisplay.length; i++){
          //check if it's in result array 
          //add to the array
        }
     }else{
        for(var i = 0; i < anDisplay.length; i++){
          //check if it's in result array 
          //delete from the array
        }
     }
     */
   }
})
```

That would be your logic for keeping track of the checked row.